# How to inject value to path variable of a web service call URL in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I want to call this backend URL to receive user profile data

```
/users/:userId/profile
```

where :userId will be an actual number for the ID.

What is the syntax to inject the userId value to the URL before sending the request?

Comment: You can refer - https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-by-example-httpclient-get/ for http get call. hope it helps.

Comment: You can pass the param as array in the routerlink. Also you can opt the way @Mohammad has answered below.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not doing router.navigate, I am doing something like httpClient.put

Answer (score 1):

One way ( using typescript ) is to use a template string

```
`/users/${this.userId}/profile`
```

The template is surrounded by the backticks ( `` ).
The string inside the backticks can evaluate expressions when they're inside a ${...}.

The string above is the same as typing:

```
'/users/' + this.userId + '/profile'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate it like string concatenation.

```
http.get('/users'/+this.userId+'/profile').then();
```